# Store video embed code in mysql database

Tags: mysql, video, embed

I want to store video embed code in mysql database.. Which is the best way to store it in database, the code can be from various video hosting services..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest following:

1. add field video_embed text;
2. make sure to sanitize the embed code before storing it
3. now, here comes tricky bit - if you allow storing html code, you should be very strict about what users are allowed to enter - if you are not checking it, users can insert any arbitrary code and perform bad things.

in a  way safer is to store url only, as it's easier to validate. also, given that you store url, it's always possible to reverse engineer the embed code ;)

so it depends on your skill and needs after all.

Comment: $code = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["embed"]); mysql_query("update table my_table set video_embed = '$code'"); although, if you ask question like that, it makes me concerned that you might not be familiar with potential risks of storing user input html code..

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to save the entire address in your database in a varchar table.

Why you ask me?

lets say you strip all the inputs of their tags and only keep the code, if something changes in the future you only have codes in your database which tells you nothing.

Try to add an dropdown with the several hosting services so you can distinguish the link.

example: 
Dropdown [youtube] --- input[youtubelink].

When you want to show the video at the front then you know what type it is and then you know how to handle the link.